# How to reflect automatic processes and processes done by different users with BPMN?

Tags: bpmn

Let's say I have the following simplified process:
[image: process]
How should I reflect there that the data could be added not only by manual input, but can be received from another system (without user verification)?
And is there more correct way to display the same actions done by different users (see `Verification` step done by `Manager 1` or `Manager 2`; in reality there are much more steps than just `Verification`, and all of them are the same in `Manager 1` and `Manager 2` columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there are many open questions regarding your specific requirements, so I can just give you an example:

[image]

I am using two lanes, one for the manager, one for the user. I assume that the concrete person (or subrole) necessary to carry out the steps for the "manager" needs to be determined within the process. From a process perspective it's just one role carried out by people with different skill sets or authorizations. I show that "Assign" task here as an automatic step, but it could also be a manual step. A BPMN process can have several start "events", I am using here two of them to show the different ways in which the process can start. I am using a collapsed pool "External System" and a message flow to indicate where the automatic message is coming from.

(Please note that BPMN processes are typically modeled from left to right, but may also be modeled from top to bottom. Also note, that for more complex processes and a more finegrained level of detail, it is often preferable to show every process participant in a separate pool with a separate process and exchange of messages in between them. Modeling one process pool with several lanes quite soon reaches practical limits!)